# Overpass recursion syntax, completely confused

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Can someone help me figure out the correct elements for the overpass recursion parameter? I just can't figure out the configuration and am a bit overwhelmed by the recursion documentation.

What I would like to retrieve is the distance of a location to the most nearby railway track. Therefore, I am trying to query:

- Railtracks that go through a radius of 50m around a fixed location and their respective node-ids
- Latitude and longitude of all railway nodes that belong to those railtracks

What I got so far is:

- http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];way(around:LATITUDE,LONGITUDE)[%22railway%22];(._;node(w););out;
  Returns all railway nodes of all railway-ways that go through the radius of 50m of the defined location. However, it also returns nodes that lie outside of the radius.
- http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];way(around:50,48.130927,11.561282)[%22railway%22];(._;%3C;);out;
  Returns the ways with all node-ids that go through the radius of 50m

Of course, I could now merge the results of both queries, however, it seems like a bit of an overhead. Does anybody know how to achieve a single query for this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured it out. If anybody is similarily confused, here is my solution:
http://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];way(around:50,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE)[%22railway%22];(._;%3E;);out;